# Can the set $\mathbb{C}^{n}$ in a natural way be considered as a real vector space?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

We have just started with Linear Algebra and the first page has the definition of a vector space. Right after that this questions comes

> Can the set $\mathbb{C}^{n}$ in a natural way be considered as a real vector space?

I guess you could consider $\mathbb{R}^{n}$ with $i$ as a scalar? Could someone try to help me understand this question.

Comment: As a real vector space of dimension $2n $...

Comment: you can consider $\mathbb{C}^n$ as the space $\mathbb{R}^{2n}$

Comment: The question is only if the basis $1,i$ of $\Bbb C$ is *natural* (even though it is certainly *canonical*). There is no intrinsic distinction between $i$ and $-i$, hence the demand for naturality may pose a problem

Comment: Could I consider the set  $\{\{x_{1}, \dots, x_{n}\},\{ix_{1}, \dots, ix_{n}\}$ where $x_{1}, \dots, x_{n}$ are basis, and with real scalars this becomes a real vector space?

Answer (score 2):

Hint:

Yes, it is a $2n-$dimensional vector space. Start from $n=1$ and note that $\mathbb{C}$ is a real vector space with standard basis $\{(1), (i)\}$ so $\mathbb{C}^n$, as a product of $n$ two dimensional vector spaces is $2n-$dimensional, and you can see a basis.

---

A vector on $\mathbb{C}^n$ over $\mathbb{R}$ has the form:
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
a_1+b_1i\\
a_2+b_2i\\
\cdot\\
\cdot\\
a_n+b_ni
\end{bmatrix}=
a_1
\begin{bmatrix}
1\\
0\\
0\\
\cdot\\
\cdot\\
0\\
\end{bmatrix}
+a_2
\begin{bmatrix}
0\\
1\\
0\\
\cdot\\
\cdot\\
0\\
0
\end{bmatrix}
+ \cdots +
a_n
\begin{bmatrix}
0\\
0\\
0\\
\cdot\\
1\\
\cdot\\
0\\
\end{bmatrix}
+b_1
\begin{bmatrix}
0\\0\\
\cdot\\
i\\
0\\
\cdot\\
0
\end{bmatrix}
+b_2
\begin{bmatrix}
0\\0\\\cdot\\
0\\
i\\
0\\
\cdot\\
0
\end{bmatrix}
+\cdots+
b_n
\begin{bmatrix}
0\\
0\\
0\\
\cdot\\
i
\end{bmatrix}
$$
with $a_i,b_i \in \mathbb{R}$.

And the $2n$ vectors at the right are linearly independent and form a basis.

Comment: And we can use real scalars and thus its a real vector space. So I think we can create $\{\{x_{1} \dots x_{n} \}, \{ix_{1}, \dots, ix_{n}\}$, which is a real vector space.

Comment: No. I've added to may answer. I hope it's useful :)

Comment: That was really helpful!

Answer (score 1):

Every complex vector space can be considered as a real vector space. This is called restriction of scalars: just forget that you had defined scalar multiplication by non-real complex numbers; all vector space axioms, over the real numbers, are obviously (still) satisfied. The notion of linear span gets more restrictive when fewer scalars are allowed, but the notion of linear independence becomes easier to satisfy; it is easy to see that in the finite dimensional case the dimension of a complex space doubles when considered as a real vector space.