# Show that $\mathbb{C}^3$ is a vector space over $\mathbb{R}$

Tags: linear-algebra, complex-numbers, vector-spaces

We know that $\mathbb{C}^3$ = {(z1, z2, z3) | z1, z2, z3 $\in$ $\mathbb{C}$}

How can I show that $\mathbb{C}^3$ is a vector space over $\mathbb{R}$?

Edit: Why was this closed? it is not a duplicate, the question is asking HOW to show something, the possible duplicate does not show how to do what this question is asking.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can the set $\mathbb{C}^{n}$ in a natural way be considered as a real vector space?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1671950/can-the-set-mathbbcn-in-a-natural-way-be-considered-as-a-real-vector-spa)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can the set $\mathbb{C}^{n}$ in a natural way be considered as a real vector space?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1671950/can-the-set-mathbbcn-in-a-natural-way-be-considered-as-a-real-vector-spa)

Comment: Well no, it doesn't show how to actually prove that it indeed is a vector space over R.

Comment: It was closed because you failed to provide any context, any demonstration of your efforts, no definitions or clarification of what you know, etc., etc. "This question needs details and clarity."

Comment: *How* you show it is the same way that you show that any structure is a vector space: verify that it satisfies the axioms.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint: for $z\in\mathbb{C}$, write $z=x+iy$. Define scalar multiplication by $rz=rx+iry$ and addition by $(x+iy)+(x'+iy'):=(x+x')+i(y+y')$. You can even prove that $\mathbb{C}^3\cong\mathbb{R}^6$

**Edit** (Since OP seems confused about this).

We have $\mathbb{C}^3=\{(z_1,z_2,z_3): z_1,z_2,z_3\in\mathbb{C}\}$. We define scalar multiplication by $r\cdot(z_1,z_2,z_3)=(rz_1,rz_2,rz_3)$ for all $r\in\mathbb{R}$ and addition by $(z_1,z_2,z_3)+(w_1,w_2,w_3):=(z_1+w_1,z_2+w_2,z_3+w_3)$.

To show that $\mathbb{C}^3$ is a vector space over $\mathbb{R}$, we need to see that

(1) $\mathbb{C}^3$ with the addition defined above is an abelian group. This is trivially true (since you asked why it is closed under addition: well, obviously $(z_1+w_1,z_2+w_2,z_3+w_3)$ is a triplet of complex numbers, that is an element of $\mathbb{C}^3$!)

(2)$ (r_1r_2)\cdot(z_1,z_2,z_3)=r_1\cdot(r_2\cdot(z_1,z_2,z_3))$ for all $r_1,r_2\in\mathbb{R}$ and $(z_1,z_2,z_3)\in\mathbb{C}^3$. Again, this is trivial.

(3) $(r_1+r_2)\cdot(z_1,z_2,z_3)= r_1\cdot(z_1,z_2,z_3)+r_2(z_1,z_2,z_3)$. Again, this is trivial.

(4) $r\cdot((z_1,z_2,z_3)+(w_1,w_2,w_3))=r\cdot(z_1,z_2,z_3)+r\cdot(w_1,w_2,w_3)$. Again, this is trivial.

(5) $1\cdot(z_1,z_2,z_3)=(z_1,z_2,z_3)$. Again... this is trivial!

If you convince yourself that (1)-(5) are true, you got it.

Now if you want to see that $\mathbb{C}^3\cong\mathbb{R}^6$, write $(z_1,z_2,z_3)$ uniquely as $(x_1+iy_1,x_2+iy_2,x_3+iy_3)$ with $x_i,y_i\in\mathbb{R}$ and define $f:\mathbb{C}^3\to\mathbb{R}^6$ by 
$$f(x_1+iy_1,x_2+iy_2,x_3+iy_3)=(x_1,y_1,x_2,y_2,x_3,y_3).$$
I leave it as an exercise to show that this is a linear isomorphism.

Comment: Thank you! I have made it to adding a vector u and w, but I'm not sure how to write the vectors, should it be e.g: u = (x1, y1, x2, y2, x3, y3), or u = (x1, iy1, x2, iy2, x3, yi3)?

Comment: @Hilbert'sHat Anyway you like. I find the first notation easier.

Comment: Sorry to bother, but could you please show the "closed under addition" for two vectors, I'm having trouble understanding how to show they are closed.

Comment: @Hilbert'sHat I have editted my post.

Comment: THAnk you! What confused me was how to show the addition when I used two vectors in the form of six elements from the mapping to R, but I see it's much easier to do that directly with z1,z2,z3, Thank you, I appreciate the effort!